# centering a span link

Tags: css, menu, html

I am trying to create menu.

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li class="xd_nav_link_1"><a href=""><span>link</span></a></li>
    <li class="xd_nav_link_2"><a href=""><span>link</span></a></li>
    <li class="xd_nav_link_3"><a href=""><span>link</span></a></li>
    <li class="xd_nav_link_4"><a href=""><span>link</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I can not focus in height is a link span.
I also like that it is centered in a: hover

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tatane/EWXtB/)
Thank

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? What do you mean by *focus*? What kind of centering do you want to achieve?

Comment: Couldn't quite understand your question, try rephrasing it.

Comment: sorry for my english.Look : http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/9996/2wdz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you just need to add a line-height equal to the height of the link.

[**JSFiddle -  Updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/G3trf/1)

```
a {
    line-height:100px;
}
```

Revised

```
a {
    line-height:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

a:hover {
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Then you need to explain further. If you also want the centering right when hovered the use a:hover {line-height:50px;}

Comment: Hmmm...I think you may need to change the hover trigger from the anchor link to the list item.

Comment: That is to say? sorry for my english